# Tkinter cambiar color del boton a transparente

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy usando tkinter para un programa sobre exportacion a .exe, e hice que al presionar un boton cambie su color con .configure, mas especificamente el fondo o "background", al presionarlo cambia a color verde y quiero que cuando presione otro boton el primero cambie a su color original, pero me di cuenta que si configuraba el fondo de boton a blanco no es el mismo color, el boton de tkinter original sin cambiar nada es como transparente y blanco juntos, si acercas la imagen se puede apreciar la diferencia y aunque no es mucha necesito el color original, hay algun color hexadecimal que sea igual a los botones normales o una funcion como background = trasparent(algo asi)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto responde a tu pregunta? Mi favorita es la cuarta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340765/default-window-colour-tkinter-and-hex-colour-codes/11342481

Comment: muchas gracias, el que me sirvio fue defaultbg = root.cget('bg')